# Google script app: insert row below all cells equalling 1

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to insert a row (automatically) below when a cell in column D = 1 (sheet1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be several approaches on this, but what I first thought was this:

#### Code:

```
function insertRowAfter1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  // get all values of column D
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, 4, lastRow, 1).getValues();
  var output = [];

  // collect all rows containing value 1 at column D
  values.forEach(function (value, index){
    if(value == 1)  
      output.push(index + 1);
  });

  // insert row after every row we have.
  // use reverse of the array to add from bottom since values will be displaced 
  // if we add from the top
  output.reverse().forEach(function (row){
    sheet.insertRowAfter(row);
  });
}
```

#### Sample Data:

[image: sample]

#### Output:

[image: output]